# Install Subversion 1.7 on Debian jessie

Tags: linux, svn, linux-kernel, debian, server

I try to install subversion 1.7 on debian jessie

1) First I follow this tutorial to add SVN 1.7 to my debian package list
http://sagar.se/svn-1.7-on-wheezy.html

2) After that I enter the following command to check if Version 1.7 is available.

```
apt-cache show subversion

Package: subversion
Version: 1.8.10-6
Installed-Size: 4621
Maintainer: Peter Samuelson <peter@p12n.org>
Architecture: amd64
Depends: libsvn1 (= 1.8.10-6), libapr1 (>= 1.4.8-2~), libaprutil1 (>= 1.2.7+dfsg), libc6 (>= 2.4), libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7), libsasl2-2
Suggests: subversion-tools, db5.3-util, patch
Description: Advanced version control system
Description-md5: 9fa4bc531e7ceb09fda8950bea636958
Homepage: http://subversion.apache.org/
Tag: devel::rcs, implemented-in::c++, implemented-in::python,
 interface::commandline, network::client, network::server,
 protocol::http, protocol::ssh, protocol::webdav, role::program,
 use::storing, use::synchronizing
Section: vcs
Priority: optional
Filename: pool/main/s/subversion/subversion_1.8.10-6_amd64.deb
Size: 921760
MD5sum: cab50d3d1cd40811aec578b7670de173
SHA1: c5e6a887ca8fdf09065d1625c283623db8d37550
SHA256: 488056c324a7201b73cc8037826d1d3587e065de5a6c37af2c524456e227124e

Package: subversion
Version: 1.7.18-1+WANdisco
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: Philip Herron <opensource@wandisco.com>
Installed-Size: 3755
Depends: libsvn1 (= 1.7.18-1+WANdisco), libapr1 (>= 1.4.8-2~), libaprutil1 (>= 1.2.7+dfsg), libc6 (>= 2.3), libneon27-gnutls, libsasl2-2
Suggests: subversion-tools, db4.8-util, patch
Filename: dists/jessie/svn17/binary-amd64/subversion_1.7.18-1+WANdisco_amd64.deb
Size: 718152
MD5sum: bebea938f9b182eebad5fe17b73a2f51
SHA1: c34e470368e590947b851c0057f5166100a62acb
SHA256: 8e7e109e8cb4f253266872da6b687b61cd7800f12e02fea50f41abe3a2eff3ac
```

3) Try to install Version 1.7

```
apt-get install subversion=1.7.18-1+WAN-disco

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 subversion : Depends: libsvn1 (= 1.7.18-1+WANdisco) but 1.8.10-6 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

With apt-cache I see that libsvn1 is installed in version 1.7.18-1+WANdisco. How can I fix the problem, that debian see only the version 1.8.10-6?

**Update:**

I try the following

```
apt-get install subversion=1.7.18-1+WANdisco libsvn1=1.7.18-1+WANdisco

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsvn1 : Depends: libserf1 (>= 1.3.7) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

As you could see in the blog, the packages were made for Debian wheezy, where only version 1.6.17 was included. For Debian jessie, I think you should stay with the version 1.8 available from the system.